# Achieving a high-availability ffmpeg system?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, high-availability

I wonder if there's a way to realize a sort of "high-availability" ffmpeg system.

Let's say, I have two Linux servers: server1 and server2, dedicated to do some video conversion with ffmpeg.

With a bash script, I can realize those jobs. But, if server1 failed to respond to the bash script, how can I deal with it and tell server2 to fill the gap?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you're looking for is an active-passive compute cluster. There are several solutions available to you, each with it's own advantages and drawbacks, so you'll need to research the available options and find the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: Okay, i'll give a look at this! Thanks :)